# What is the type of Starcraft 2 games where you have a fixed amount of resources?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am pretty new to StarCraft 2, and I was wondering if there is a name or a way to search for StarCraft 2 games that start you off with a certain amount of resources and you are unable to farm any more.  I feel this would be more like the Warhammer 40k table top game, as it would basically be a pure micro game.

Comment: Are you looking for games to play *like* SC2 that *aren't* SC2, or do you want to search for a specific type of SC2 match set with certain options?

Comment: There is one map they play a lot on Team Liquid Attack, called "Kulas Extreme" (word play of Kulas Ravine, an old ladder map). It's a normal melee game, but starts you off with near infinite resources. It's basically a ridiculous game though because economy is *essential* to sc2 gameplay. For example as protoss, a good build is to instantly build like 100 pylons and 100 nexuses (for chrono boost). Already you can see how it's just chaos, not a micro game. When White Ra played this map as Protoss versus mass mutalisk, his strategy was to just make as many zealots as possible. And won.

Comment: @JohntheGreen looking for a specific type of SC2 match. I have heard about it, but I don't know how to find it.
tenfour: thats a start, but yeah, too chaotic. Looking for a map that you have 15k of resources and that's it

Comment: In case anyone's interested: [VOD of the game tenfour was talking about](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Uw3o0EY58wU#t=3289s).

Comment: Do you mean a game where all the other mechanics remain the same as the usual multiplayer melee games?

Comment: I believe there isn't a way to search for a type of game of which you described. You would simply have to look through endless custom matches.

Answer (score 1):

The game does not come with the type of game/map that you describe.

You can look for third party map. In Multiplayer, Custom games, you can "Join a Game" or "Create a Game".

These categories will be available:

- Melee
- Co-op vs AI
- Tower Defense
- Tug of War
- Custom

The **Custom category** is the type of game/map. There is no fine grained way of finding what you describe from within the game client.

*(note: the current game client is Version 1.4.3.21029)*

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SC2!! :D

If you are looking to get started on a pure micro game, I recommend [Marine Arena](http://marine-arena.wikia.com/wiki/Marine_Arena_Wiki).

Technically its not pure micro, because you get money from killing other players' units in order to buy upgrades, but it is just about all micro.

(Btw, you do get other units than just marines)

As for a custom game which had a limited set of resources and you just 'played it out', haven't heard of one.